# What does the "-A" in a Shimano "FC-M171-A" crankset mean?

Tags: shimano, crankset

The FC-M171 and FC-M171-A are listed separately in [Shimano's spec sheet](https://productinfo.shimano.com/download?path=pdfs/archive/2015-2016_Specifications_v024_en.pdf) (p73-74), but I can't see any difference between the listed specifications. Curious, as my old crankset was FC-M171 and the replacement that I've just fitted is labelled FC-M171-A. It's not the crank arm length.

Comment: Can you see any difference between them? country of origin?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the A is a different tooth count. The normal one is 42-32-24T, and the A model is 48-38-28T.

Image from their 2017 dealer support manual.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the [spec](https://productinfo.shimano.com/download?path=pdfs/archive/2015-2016_Specifications_v024_en.pdf) (and the screenshot) show **both** the "A" and "non-A" are available in 48-38-28 (while the non-A is **also** available in 42-34-24). So it's not as simple as just different tooth count, unfortunately!

Comment: Hmmm true, i'll dig deeper and amend my answer when I find one.

Comment: Looking at the exploded views (EV) of both FC-M171 & M171A, the chain guards are different part numbers and look slightly different.  On the EV for 171A it has an interchangeability table of parts with M171 and it notes the chain guards are a "B" fit which means they can be interchanged but look different.

Comment: @Jeff thanks, just seen this. Sounds like that's right - I'd mark it as solved if it was an answer instead of a comment!